# Download a file stored in CRM from a php webpage

Tags: php, curl, download, crm

I have a website that pulls customer cases from our CRM (SugarCRM) the cases and case notes can have attachments which are stored in the CRM. Sugar has a built in API endpoint to get the file data and return it via a curl request using:

//:record/file/:field as a GET request

my curl script

```
    public static function getAttachment($url, $encode = false) 
{
    self::connect_sugarcrm();

    $curl = curl_init(self::$SUGARENDPOINTURI.self::$API.$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Authorization: Bearer",
            "OAuth-Token: ".self::$tokens->access_token,
        )
    );

    $response       = curl_exec($curl);
    $header_size    = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $headers        = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $file           = substr($response, $header_size);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($encode) {
        return base64_encode($file);
    }

    return $file;
```

I'm not setting encode to true so just returning the raw file rather than it encoded as Base64. I'm getting the correct response from CRM as documented.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 14:01:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Expires: 
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
Pragma: 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Copy of Countries by region.xlsx"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
ETag: d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
Content-Length: 59349
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

I am now trying to figure out how i then get the browser to download this file. Do i need to save this file locally before initialising the download or is there a way to just get it to download?

My header script

```
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Copy of Countries by region.xlsx"');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: 59349');
    // echo base64_decode($data);
    echo $file;
    exit();
```

This will download a 56KB excel file but it cant be opened so I wanted to see what I was doing wrong with the headers

I can get a variety of files to download with the following headers

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file->name}\""); 
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Length: ".$file->{'content-length'}."");
ob_clean();
flush();

echo $data;
exit;
```

However this causes errors with some file types such as psd xslx but works fine for jpg,png,gif,pdf,docx,csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading into PHP headers I have got my download.php to successfully download files stored in my CRM with the following code

ref: https://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Curl script to fetch files from CRM

```
public static function download($url)
{
    self::connect_sugarcrm();

    $curl = curl_init(self::$SUGARENDPOINTURI.$url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "OAuth-Token: ".self::$tokens->access_token,
        )
    );

    $response       = curl_exec($curl);
    $header_size    = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $headers        = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $file           = substr($response, $header_size);

    curl_close($curl);
    return $file;
}
```

Download.php

```
$module         = get_query_var('module');
$id             = get_query_var('id');
$url            = "{$module}/{$id}/file";
$fileinfo       = MagiConnect_SugarCRM::getSugar('', $url);

foreach ($fileinfo as $file) {
    $data       = MagiConnect_SugarCRM::download($file->uri);

    ob_end_clean();
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: ".$file->{'content-type'});
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file->name}\""); 
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header("Content-Length: ".$file->{'content-length'}."");

    echo $data;
    exit;
}
```